# Interesting property of a divisor contained in special fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $(A, \mathfrak{m}, \kappa=A/\mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring and $f:X \to \operatorname{Spec} (A)$
a scheme. Let $D \subset X$ a divisor on $X$ contained in special fiber $D \subset f^{-1}(\sigma_{\mathfrak{m}})$ with associated
ideal sheaf $I_D$.

Assume we know
that $I_D$ is generated by a power of $\mathfrak{m}$, means
there exist a $n$ with $I_D = \mathfrak{m}^nO_X$. The structure morphism induces
natural morphism of sheaves $\mathfrak{m}^n \otimes_A \kappa  \to I_D \otimes_{O_X} O_D$ and this induces a morphism
on global sections $\mathfrak{m}^n \to H^0(D, I_D \otimes_{O_X} O_D)$.

What do we know about the last morphism? When is that an surjection?

Comment: So, you want your local ring $A$ of Krull dimension 1. And do you want $D$ to be Cartier, which probably means that $A$ should be a DVR?

Comment: @abx: No, I not require that $A$ should have dimension $1$, for example $A$ could be
an affine surface and $X$ the blowup of the closed point of $A$.